# No adapter attached; skipping layout in fragment using firebase database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have gone through most of the topics related to it and couldn't find the proper solution.
I am getting an error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" when retrieving the data from firebase database to my fragments using recycler view.
Please see the code below:

**Resources :**

**Fragment file**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;


public class TempFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView rcv;
    private ArrayList<TempModel> tempData;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public TempFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
        rcv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycle_template);
        rcv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3));
        rcv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        fireAdapter();
        return v;
    }
    public void fireAdapter(){
        tempData = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("images");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TempModel tempModel = postSnapshot.getValue(TempModel.class);
                    tempData.add(tempModel);
                }
                TempAdapter  tempAdapter = new TempAdapter(getContext(),tempData);
                rcv.setAdapter(tempAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class TempAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TempAdapter.MyViewHol> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<TempModel> data ;

    public TempAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TempModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHol onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view ;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHol(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHol holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        Picasso.get().load(data.get(position).getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
       // holder.imageView.setImageResource(data.get(position).getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHol extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView ;
        ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHol(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_title);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_img);

        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class TempModel {
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;

    public TempModel(){

    }

    public TempModel(String name, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

I know there are few things i'm missing on it.
It will be great if anyone help on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Debugger to check if you are getting data from firebase database?
Or try to Init your Adaptor in OnCreateview method and use notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: I apologize for delays,I think some other posted the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Adapter inside `onCreateView` then when new data arrives simply call adapter to `notifyDataSetChaged`

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp, container, false);
        youradapter = new TempAdapter(getContext(),new ArrayList<TempModel>());
        rcv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycle_template);          
        rcv.setAdapter();
        rcv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3));
        rcv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        fireAdapter();
        return v;
    }
```

Then inside `onDataChange` callback

```
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         TempModel tempModel = postSnapshot.getValue(TempModel.class);
         tempData.add(tempModel);
       }
       TempAdapter  tempAdapter = new TempAdapter(getContext(),tempData);
       yourAdapter.setData(tempData);
        }
```

Then inside your `TempAdapter` class create `setData` function

```
public void setData(List<TempModel> list) {
   if (data != null) data.clear();
   if (data == null) data = new ArrayList<>();
   data.addAll(list);
   notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried it , there is no error on adapter. But the data is not fetched in my fragment view. Whereas i tried on normal activity , it works fine. 
Can you tell me any work around?

Comment: After data arriving, you can't see it on the Fragment view. But it is working on Activity View.  Am I right?

Comment: yes exactly. i cannot see data in fragment view, whereas in activity view it is shown.

Comment: Sure ,I guess the code i shared is the code i have but anyway do you want me to share here or anywhere like email

Comment: Ok one more thing, move everything inside onCreateView function into onViewCreated function, hope it will work

Comment: I tried that as well, but still the data is not shown in the fragment view. If possible can you send me as what all i should add in the onViewCreated function.