# How to show recycler view on button pressed in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to include a search functionality in my app. So when the user presses the search button, the results are shown in a recycler view. But when the user presses the button, `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` error pops up. There is no error when the recycler is directly loaded in `onCreate()` method. How to solve this issue?
The activity code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        binding.searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               search_start();
            }
        });
    }
private void search_start(){
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                    .setPageSize(5)
                    .build();
            Query mQuery;
            mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("tests");
            FirestorePagingOptions<SearchItem> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<SearchItem>()
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .setQuery(mQuery, config, SearchItem.class)
                    .build();
            adapter = new SearchAdapter(options);
            binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: because when create you not set your adapter for recycler view. just create empty list to adapter and initialize it when create. You said: "There is no error when the recycler is directly loaded in onCreate() method.". It wrong, when you activity create, your adapter have not set adapter yet. recyclerview is setup when you click the button

Comment: Please have look https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511956/8342718

Answer (score 0):

Just set the adapter in **OnCreate()** and Send a Empty list in it

```
adapter = new SearchAdapter(options);
binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In Your Adapter create a setList() function

```
void setList(FirestorePagingOptions<SearchItem> options){
    this.options = options;
}
```

And on the Search Button ClickListener() set the list

```
adapter.setList(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the RecyclerView in `onCreate` but feed data to adapter later in search function.

In adapter you can have a method which takes the data and adds those to adapter and make sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` post adding data which will refresh the RecyclerView.

Inside Adapter :

```
public void addOptions(FirestorePagingOptions <SearchItem> options){
    this.options = options;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Inside Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    initRecyclerView();
    setupEventHandlers();

}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    adapter = new SearchAdapter();
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupEventHandlers() {
    binding.searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchStart();
        }
    });
}

private void searchStart() {
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(2)
        .setPageSize(5)
        .build();
    Query mQuery;
    mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("tests");
    FirestorePagingOptions < SearchItem > options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder < SearchItem > ()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(mQuery, config, SearchItem.class)
        .build();

    adapter.addOptions(options);

}
```