# Android Kotlin RecyclerView Adapter onCreateViewHolder no called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

This is my adapter creation.

```
        groupsAdapter = GroupsAdapter(groupsVM)
        groupsRecyclerView.apply {
            // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
            // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
            setHasFixedSize(false)
            // specify an viewAdapter
            adapter = groupsAdapter
            // use a linear layout manager
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }
```

Then I set a listener of the viewmodel

```
       groupsVM.groupNames.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {
            groupsAdapter.setData(it)
        })
```

Above code is in the  view.

Then, this is my adapter class

```
class GroupsAdapter()
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupsAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    private var dataList = emptyList<Pair<String, String>>()

    fun setData(groupNameList: List<Pair<String, String>>){
        dataList = groupNameList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class MyViewHolder(private val view: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        val groupView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.group_view) as View
        val groupNameTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.group_name) as TextView
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
            MyViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).
            inflate(R.layout.group, parent, false) as View
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val group = dataList[position]
        if (group != null) {
            holder.groupNameTextView.text = group.second
        }
    }

}
```

When getItemCount is called and return a positive value and I also expect onCreateViewHolder to be called as well.
But onCreateViewHolder is never called.
Can you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you enabled `setHasFixedSize(true)`. Did you check the first call to `getItemCount()` does not return 0?

Comment: Yes, it returns 0 the first time. I set fixedSize to false, but still nothing happens...

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511956/8342718

Comment: You should avoid passing ViewModel in the Adapter constructor, instead set default data or pass empty list  as initial data to your adapter constructor.

Comment: I've changed the code, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Add this function to your adapter:

```
var dataList = emptyList<String>()

fun setData(groupNameList:List<String>){
    dataList = groupNameList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

And set the data when your observer receives a data:

```
 groupsVM.groupNames.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer {
        groupsAdapter.setData(it)
    })
```

Comment: It is never called. The same with onBindViewHolder.

Comment: What does your `getItemCount` returns each time? Is its size list the same as you want or is it zero?

Comment: It is the size I want

Comment: And where did you set data to your adapter?

Comment: onBindViewHolder function

Answer (score 0):

I just used your code and it works fine and onCreateViewHolder() gets called.
the problem is certainly not with this code, it must be somewhere else like in your layouts